# Python dictionaries - Why do keys(), values() return lists, not sets?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, unordered

From the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31479847/if-dictionaries-arent-ordered-why-do-two-dictionaries-with-the-same-key-names) I understand that dictionaries in general are not ordered, at least not in a reliable fashion. So why do the dictionary methods keys(), values(), items() return ordered lists instead of e.g. unordered sets? Is it just a matter of convenience or is there some underlying reasoning?

Comment: First, `values` are *not* guaranteed unique..

Comment: Dictionary keys and values (if iterated over separately) are always in the same order. Using sets for either would make this impossible.

Answer (score 10):

They don't return lists or sets; they return views. Key views are set-like, and item views are set-like as long as the values are hashable, but value views cannot be set-like, as there can be duplicate values.

Before Python 3, they returned lists, but those methods predated the introduction of sets. [Sets were introduced in Python 2.4](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), while `keys`/`values`/`items` have been around since at least [1.4](https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/lib/node13.html#SECTION00316000000000000000), and probably before 1.0.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, this really helps.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html), the `sets` module wasn't introduced until Python 2.3, well after the dictionary type was established. It would have been a breaking change to redefine how `keys()`, `values()` etc worked.

In Python 3, those functions return *view objects* rather than lists which, while iterable, don't suggest an explicit ordering in the way that an ordered list does.

Comment: Note in Python 3.7+, dictionaries should be considered ordered.